# Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class: soapclient in

Tags: php, soap

its works by hit url but in cronjob script not workes.Cannot instantiate non-existent class:  soapclient in command prompt.

```
$wsdl ='********/InvoicingService?wsdl';
$client  = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace"=> 1,"exceptions" => 0));
$invoicecheck = array("username" => "*****","password" => "*****","invoiceNo" =>"****");
$proxy = $client->getProxy();
$value2 = $client ->checkInvStatus($invoicecheck);
$statusInvoice=$value2->return->responseMessage;

if($statusInvoice=='Paid'){
    mail('mahtab46@gmail.com','wsdl check cron mail','paid');
    echo 'working';
} else {
    echo 'not worked';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cronjob executes the PHP CLI handler. This probably uses a different php.ini that doesn't load the soap extension. Try to have php run a `php -i > /tmp/test.txt` or something and see if the Soap functionality is in there?

Comment: hi..hosting server no soap client installed in php cli.so how to call soap client in php cli.on Php browser hit showing already installed but php cli no and have no permission.

Comment: If the PHP-version of your host is older than PHP 5.3 (I really hope not) you can try to use dl() to load the extension manually. Otherwise I'm afraid you'll have to ask them to add the extension to the cli ini.